Is the Classical limit of Quantum theory the Newtonian Mechanics?
Recently I started to study Quantum Dissipative models like Caldeira-Leggett model and it occurs to me that this model provides a Quantum to Classical transition, but the Classical resultant system satisfy Brownian motion, i.e., it is completely stochastic.
I know little about decoherence models, but reading the simple qubit model proposed by Zurek, it seems to happens something similar: there is a selection of the accessible states caused by the dynamics with the environment, but the remaining system is not yet a Classical complete deterministic system, but some stochastic system, with some randomness in it.
My question is: is it standard for quantum to classical transitions? Do we ever recover some stochastic classical system?
In affirmative case, could we say that stochastic mechanics is a generalization of Classical mechanics? I always thought that Determinism was one of the basis of Classical theory and one of the guiding principles to identify a Classical Theory. But thinking about the Classical to Quantum transition, it occurred to me that we could have a situation where There are more general non-quantum theories than the Newtonian or relativistic mechanics, from which these are special cases, and possibly a Quantum to Classical transition could result in such model, not necessarily Newtonian Mechanics.
If negative, where could we find examples of quantum-to-classical transitions resulting in systems with complete deterministic behavior?

In the very large distance-scale limit where $h\approx 0$, quantum mechanics is adequately approximated by classical mechanics, isn’t it?

@controlgroup I was thinking more about to recover Classical theory through some dynamic process, like dissipation or decoherence. About this limit, I only know the Ehrenfest theorem and Stationary Phase approximation, but these limits are deterministic?

The standard conventional classical limit goes through phase space QM, at scales where its Wigner distributions appear like Dirac deltas moving almost classically in phase space. First, familiarize yourself with simple paradigm systems, and only then move on to trickier, recondite settings which sharpen your questions….

@CosmasZachos could you indicate an example of such simple paradigm systems?

In my opinion, stochastic mechanics obviously is a generalization of classical mechanics, just like anything stochastic is a generalization of something deterministic. But maybe you had something different in mind?

The oscillator in this booklet is a "must".

In the classical limit quantum information is lost/sacrificed, so the entropy increases (!) as per footnote 1 here.

This is a more general result than what I was expecting! Thank you for sharing it. I think it answers my question. If you want to transform your comments in an answer, I will accept it!

Not sure how to shape it to answer an unstated underlying question. The paper linked addresses the somewhat delicate issue... There is also a talk writeup...

The situation is more complicated. Contrary to much that is written about the classical limit, there are different types of classical theories, for example classical field theory. If we start with a quantum field theory and take the classical limit one would expect to obtain classical field theory. However, if you do this with the popular phase space approach you end up with classical mechanics. Therefore, I think the way Planck's constant is used in such phase space approaches is misleading.

In classical physics a measurable quantity such as the $x$ position has equations of motion written in terms of variables $x(t)$ and when you measure the $x$ position at time $t$ you get the value $x(t)$.
In quantum physics, the equation of motion of some measurable quantity like the $x$ position is written in terms of a Hermitian operator called an observable whose eigenvalues are the possible results of measuring that quantity. Quantum physics predicts the probability of each of the possible values. In general to predict the result of an experiment you have to take into account what happens to all of the possible values of a measurable quantity: this is called quantum interference. For a simple example see Section 2 of
https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9911150
As a result of interference the square amplitudes of the eigenstates of an observable in general don't obey the rules of probability.
When information is copied out of a quantum system this suppresses interference and results in amplitudes that do obey the rules of probability to a good approximation: an effect called decoherence. In the context of the equations of motion used in quantum theory this usually results in probability distributions that are sharply peaked around classical equations of motion on the scales of space and time in everyday life. Here are some papers reviewing decoherence:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.06282
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0306072
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0501119
https://arxiv.org/abs/0903.1802
https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.2187
